# How to work with groups of a data set in C#

Tags: c#

This is a specific question to answer a general problem. I am trying to work with groups of a dataset (this is pulled from a sql query).

For example, I am trying to find if all files needed for a package exist.

Here is my dataset:

```
Package       FilePath
Package1      fp1
Package1      fp2
Package2      fp3
Package2      fp4
```

...

I want my result to be:

```
Package      filesExist
Package1     true
Package2     false
```

The checking of files is not my problem.

I am asking about how to work with a group in a dataset.

Thank you.

Comment: `GroupBy(dataset => dataset.Package).Where(x => x.All(y => CheckFile(y.FilePath)));` Something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a sequence of objects with at least two properties `Package` and `FilePath` and you want a result sequence of objects with property `FilesExists` if all files of `Package` exist.

First you group your dataset by Package:

```
var groupsWithSamePackage = dataset.GroupBy(
    data => data.Package,          // make groups with same Package as Key
    data => data.FilePath);        // each group has FilePath as members
```

The result is a sequence of groups where each group has a Key with a Package value and all items in the group are the FilePaths of the elements in your Dataset that have this Key:

```
key = Package1, items = {fp1, fp2},
key = Package2, items = {fp3, fp4},
key = ...,      items = all FilePaths with Package equal to key,
```

The second step is to check each group to see if all FilePaths in the group exist:

```
var result = groupsWithSamePackage
    .Select(group => new
    {
        Package = group.Key,
        FilesExist = group.All(groupItem => FileExist(groupItem)
    });
```

Finished, Simple comme bonjour!

Comment: GroupBy is not appearing as a method to dataset. Am I missing an assembly reference? For reference, I am using VS2012.

Comment: Enumerable.GroupBy extension of IEnumerable is in System.Linq. Google voor Enumerable Groupby for details. Or: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501(v=vs.110).aspx